# Creating routes dynamically in Svelte

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm creating a Svelte SPA as a wrapper for an API. I get all data (content, menu items) from this API and I would like to create these routes dynamically. I have only one page (Mypage.svelte) and its content is updated depending on the menu link I click. Currently I am using the *[svelte-spa-router](https://github.com/ItalyPaleAle/svelte-spa-router)* where I define the menu URLs manually:

```
export const routes = {
  "/group0": Mypage,
  "/group1": Mypage,
  "/group2": Mypage,
  "/group3": Mypage,
  "/group4": Mypage,
  "*": NotFound
};
```

Is it possible in Svelte or SvelteKit to set these dummy routes dynamically for example by preloading them from my API?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware it is not possible to generate routes dynamically the way you describe

Although there might be an alternative at hand.

### SvelteKit

In SvelteKit the routes are generated by the file System. [Docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing)
You can define a Layout for your app and for every Sub Folder [Docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#layout)
and pass arguments as part of the URL [Docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing)

This way you could determine a Layout and pass a parameter via URL and fetch your data accordingly.

Depending on how variant your data is, this might be an option.